# Angular array won't show nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to show a nested array in `AngularJS`. However, I can't get it to work.

Controller:

```
$scope.selected_category = [];
$scope.categories = [];

$scope.getCategories = function() {
    ItemService.getCategories().success(function(categories) {
        $scope.categories = categories;
    });
}

$scope.getCategories();
```

The form setting `$scope.selected_category`

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected_category">
    <option ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{ category }}">{{ category.name }}</option>
</select>
```

So... now printing `{{ selected_category }}` show the expected array with a `subcategory` array inside:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "clothing",
  "subcategories": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "jackets",
      "item_category_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "jeans",
      "item_category_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "sweaters",
      "item_category_id": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hooowever, when I try to do `selected_category.subcategories` I get nothing. Why is that?

Here's a plunker with the reproduced problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/AtqpXogmItdSupEZGt7R?p=preview

Comment: In your plunker you're assigning `category.name` and not the actual category object to `selected_category`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-options`:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected_category" 
ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories">
</select>
```